# How to keep html formating in jsp

Tags: java, html, servlets

I need to pass html code into jsp page so I make an ajax request from the same page to update a div.

servlet code:

```
String greetings = "<h1>Hello from servlet</h1>";
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(greetings);
```

jsp:

```
<div id="ajaxGetUserServletResponse"></div>
```

I get on page: `<h1>Hello from servlet</h1>` istead of html representation of h1 tag. How to fix it to preserve html formating in jsp?

#### Edit:

Sending HTML response from server is not recommended. You could have left the `<h1>` tags in the JSP as well. However, if you insist on doing so this should set it up for you

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

out.println("<h1>Hello from servlet</h1>");
```

Comment: why would you put your layout in your java code? that's what the jsp file is for.

Comment: @Stultuske well, I know but there is some cases when it's usefull to do this way

Comment: You asked the wrong question. Reframe it to *"I have some HTML code in a JavaScript string variable like so [...], I'd like to add it to the below HTML element in the document [...], I'm currently trying to do so [...], but it appears as text instead of as HTML."* Fill in the blanks and retag to JavaScript/HTML. This all has completely nothing to do with Java/JSP/Servlets.

Comment: @BalusC actully my HTML code is not in the JavaScript string variable but in servlet. The javascript is only make an ajax request to servlet.

Comment: You did not understand me nor webdev basics. The JS  code making an ajax request ultimately gets that HTML in a string variable which you then put in that div. It's exactly that step which is done wrong. It's not different having that HTML string in a hardcoded JS variable instead of obtained from the ajax response. Again, reframe your question as said and fill in the blanks with code you used.

Comment: @BalusC aparently the reason was in using javascript text() method istead of html() when passing data into corresponding id, so the question is resolved.

Comment: Glad you understood the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Sending HTML response from server is not recommended. You could have left the `<h1>` tags in the JSP as well However, if you insist on doing so this should set it up for you

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

out.println("<h1>Hello from servlet</h1>");
```

Comment: I wanted to write this as a comment, since I do not have 50 reps I had to answer